# Complex if-statement in an textchanged event

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, indexof, textchanged

I want to realize a complex if-statement. The if-statement is in an textchanged event of a textbox. If the if-statement gives true, a pdf-file should be load. The problem is not how to load the PDF-file, thats works already fine, the problem is, how set the if-statement. There, the following conditions should be queried:

At position 0 must be an "S",
at position 1 must be an "E",
at position 2 must be an "H",
position 3 does not matter,
position 4-7 represent a number and the number must be from 0-3000 (not allowed to go over 3000),
at position 8 must be again an "H" or an "R"

I tried it with the method IndexOf() and it works for the first 3 characters, but in connection with the 8th sign it did not work anymore. I think it is related to the fact that "H" already exists at position 2.

To check the number I tried it with: 
Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.Substring(4, 4)) <= 3000

But that did not work either.

Comment: You could try a regular expression `^SEH.(3000|[0-2]\d\d\d)[HR]$`

Answer (score 1):

```
private static bool ShowPdf(string str)
{
    if (str[0] != 'S')
        return false;
    else if (str[1] != 'E')
        return false;
    else if (str[2] != 'H')
        return false;
    else if (str[8] != 'H' && str[8] != 'R')
        return false;
    else if (int.TryParse(str.Substring(4,4), out int number)
        return (number >= 0 && number <= 3000);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `ElementAt` for a `string`.  It has an indexer built in `if(str[0] != 'S')`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I found the first answer from Jonathon Chase also very helpful, but this answer is no longer available. Sorry, Im new here and dont understand why the first answer disappeard. Could this first answer be reupload?

Comment: @Rafael That answer was wrong.  I pointed out the problem and Jonathon deleted the answer and was apparently going to edit and then un-delete it but never did.  FYI once you have high enough rep you can also see deleted answers.